# The most pythonic way to use try and catch

Tags: python

```
def deploy_stack(region: str, props: Properties) -> Any:
   try:
        return cloudformation_resource(region).create_stack(**props)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as err:
        if "AlreadyExistsException" in str(err):
            return (
                cloudformation_resource(region)
                .Stack(props["StackName"])
                .update(**props)
            )
        else:
            raise err
```

I am wondering if my try catch block is the most pythonic here. I am open to suggestions. This is more of a way for me to learn how to be more pythonic than anything else. There isn't a bug but i feel this block of code may be odd.

Comment: Check out our sister site [CodeReview.SE] for a place to get feedback for working code.

Comment: Not sure why the "belongs on another stackexchange site" flag doesn't include codereview, it seems questions of this nature are asked pretty often

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sure i can move the question over there. should i close this?

Comment: Can't you just catch errors of type `AlreadyExistsException` instead of checking a string?

Comment: As above (this is a bit off topic)... But... can you not catch a `AlreadyExistsException` directly? If not, you could negate the if and simply `raise` (no need to `raise err`), to remove the `else` condition.

Comment: @Dinero I posted an answer, but you might get more detailed feedback at CodeReview.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice to be fair to you i will accept your answer here but in future i will post my code-review questions to the other site. i apologize.

Comment: @MLarionov see [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353)

Comment: The contents of the migration list seems to be entirely arbitrary and barely useful. At the very least, it should have an "other"  option to specify a different site.

Comment: @chepner You may have looked at that link I mentioned for Mlarionov but in case not please see [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353)

Comment: I did; restricting the list to the 5 most frequently migrated sites counts as "arbitrary" in my book; just because they are the *most* commonly used doesn't mean they are *commonly* used. superuser.com is the only one I've even been tempted to use in the last 8 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just catch `AlreadyExistsException` and let all other exceptions continue through the default mechanism:

```
def deploy_stack(region: str, props: Properties) -> Any:
   try:
        return cloudformation_resource(region).create_stack(**props)
   except botocore.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException:
        return (
            cloudformation_resource(region)
            .Stack(props["StackName"])
            .update(**props)
        )
```

Comment: That final `except` clause is completely redundant.

Comment: @Attie I was modifying the existing code. Both of you make a good point that the second `except` is not needed.

Comment: would removing the last raise err not mean we won't catch other types of errors?

Comment: @Dinero - an uncaught exception will continue up through the stack, as though there wasn't a `try`/`except` block here.

Comment: oh i see so you are saying that even though i am rasing an err and not doing anything about it it is, i should just let it trickle up?

Comment: @Dinero Yes, that is the other half of my answer that was suggested by other people in the comments.